# Get anchor ids and convert to a JavaScript array

Tags: jquery, load

How can I use jQuery to obtain all the ids of the anchors within a specific div and convert them to a array for passing over a load/get method?

The HTML will be in the following format:

```
<div id="a div id">
   <div style="some styling">
      <span><a href="" id="the_id_1"/></span>
      <span><a href="" id="the_id_2"/></span>
      <span><a href="" id="the_id_3"/></span>
   </div>
</div>
```

So in theory I'm after passing the ids of the anchors over a load method so I can refresh the content of a div based on the selected ids.

Edit #1

The id is slightly different from what I mention above.

Here is the function I'm using to obtain the id number from the anchors:

```
function getSelectedTierPanels(tierId) {
    var container = $('#tier'+tierId+' a').map(function() { 
        return this.id.match(/\d+$/);
    }).get();
    alert(container);
    return container;
}
```

Comment: You should note `<a />` is causing errors (at least on Firefox), you should change that to `<a></a>`.

Comment: Sorry, this isn't a copy of code, I manually typed it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Similar to [TJ's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3657938/get-anchor-ids-and-convert-to-a-javascrtipt-array/3657970#3657970), but uses the [*map()*](http://api.jquery.com/map/) function to create a new jQuery object containing all the IDs, followed by [*get()*](http://api.jquery.com/get/) to get a normal array from the object:

```
var anchors = $('#a_div_id a').map(function () { return this.id; }).get();
```

---

To get just the number from the id in the format `the_id_1`, `the_id_2`, you can use one of my favourite techniques - splitting and popping:

```
var anchors = $('#a_div_id a').map(function () { 
    return this.id.split("_").pop();
}).get();
```

This technique splits the string into an array at each `_`.  The *pop()* method removes and returns the last item of the array, which is just the number in this case.  If you wanted a different part of the array, you could refer to the item's index directly.

---

If your `id` is slightly different, then a regular expression might be better than splitting.  What you have currently is `return this.id.match(/\d+$/);`, which is just fine except that *match()* returns an array so you need to access the first element of that array to retrieve the full match:

```
return this.id.match(/\d+$/)[0];
```

Note that this would throw an error if there was no successful match, so you're better off storing match to a variable:

```
var match = this.id.match(/\d+$/);
return match ? match[0] : null;
```

Comment: My anchor ids are are alpha-numeric representation of a record id, e.g. "the_id_1_" 1 would be the record id. How can I only import this into the array. I like both methods but Andy E yours seems less of a foot-print.

Comment: @user: I've updated my answer with an example on how to just get the number for you.

Comment: @user: it doesn't make sense that you would get `NaN` here, there are no number operations included in this code.  Are you sure the id is of the format `the_id_1` ?

Comment: Ah I see, so in theory nothing was being returned. I've added the return match ? statement as initially my function won't return anything.

Comment: I've noticed as well that this appears to be returning the id of my container div as well I.e. <div id="a div id"> as part of the array.

Comment: Ah it's because when I generate new blocks after the initial one, I add a remove link with an id. See amended post.

Comment: i fixed the problem by on targeting links with a specific class which I already had in place.

Answer (score 3):

```
function get_all_idz() {
    var array_idz = new Array();
    var total = $(".row_id").length;
    for(a=0; a<=total-1; a++)
    {
        var abc = $(".row_id").eq(a).attr('id');
        array_idz[a] = abc;
    }
    alert(array_idz);
}
/*IT WILL STORE IN ARRAY LIKE (10,11,12,13,14,15)*/
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should work:

```
var anchors = [];
$('#a_div_id a').each(function() {
    // `this` is the actual `a` element
    if (a.id) {
        anchors.push(a.id);
    }
});
```

The selector "#a_div_id a" (note I've changed the ID a bit to make it work; no spaces allowed in IDs for use in selectors) looks for all `a` elements that are descendants of the element with the ID "a_div_id". jQuery's [`each`](http://api.jquery.com/each/) loops through them, with each call to the iterator function setting `this` to the actual `a` element (not a jQuery object for it). From the `a` element instance, you can query the `id` property, which is a reflection of the `id` attribute.

Comment: +1, I'm fairly certain this would be a little faster than *map()* if speed was an issue.

Comment: @Andy E: (I see you've dropped the "head" -- good move. ;) ) Cheers. Of course, if speed is *really* an issue, you'd want to drop the `each` out as well and use a boring loop. :-)